# Using instance functions from constructor using WinJS

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have a function defined roughly as follows:

```
var myNamespace = WinJS.Namespace.define("MyNamespace", {    
    myClass: WinJS.Class.define(
        function (myVariable) {
             myFunction(myVariable);
        },
        {
            myFunction: function FunctionMine(myVariable) {
            // Do stuff
            }
        ...
```

I'm using WinJS to write a windows store app, and the above format doesn't seem to work - it doesn't recognise `myFunction` as a function.  Is it possible to reference an instance member of the class from the class constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "this.myFunction".

Your function isn't in the scope to let you call it in that way.